# What is the best place to put response security headers, Laravel app code or nginx?

Tags: php, laravel, security, nginx

As far as i understand, i can put response security headers(like X-Content-Type, X-Frame-Options) in laravel app or nginx. What is the best place for it. Advantages and drowbacks?

Comment: If you want to globally do something, the server config is often the best choice. If your code demands something, sometimes it is better to have these in the code, however, so that you can guarantee that they are set (although the server can still override). If you are developing local, it is sometimes more convenient to have it in code, too. If you are both the server admin, and the developer, it sometimes doesn’t matter. Server configs are more prone to be lost during a server migration, too, unfortunately

Comment: Keep in mind Laravel only handles PHP requests so if it's something you need to also send for resources like e.g. images you need to set those on the webserver